# Updating Spring @Scheduled Cron From Properties File

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, cron, war

I have a method scheduled using Spring's `@Scheduled` annotation with a cron expression loaded from a properties file, as described in [this](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-using-environment-specific-cron-expressions-with-the-scheduled-annotation/) article. The application that this scheduled method is contained in is deployed as a .war file on a Tomcat application server.

This works properly and the scheduled method runs as expected in correspondence with the cron expression given in the properties file.

My question is, if I want to change when the method executes, and I modify the cron expression in the properties file, would I need to redeploy the application for the change to take effect?

Comment: You need not re-deploy the application. You can just update cron expression in the properties file and re-start the application. In the next run, the new cron expression will be used to schedule.

Comment: How do you mean 're-start' the application? It is a war file that contains no main method and the method annotated with @Scheduled is run only via the Spring scheduler. Do you mean re-start the Tomcat application server?

Comment: Sorry, I should have told re-start the server (Tomcat web server). The best practice is to always keep the properties file outside of your war file so that it is easier to update the properties. If you are obligated to keep the properties file within the war file, then deploy the war file in exploded format. So that you can still update the properties directly without the need to generating the new war.

Answer (score 0):

Since the war file is deployed in exploded format, the properties file can be updated directly without generating a new war and/or redeploying. For the changed property to take effect in the @Scheduled annotation, either:

- The Tomcat application server can be restarted (thanks @Mithun, didn't think of this for some reason).

OR

- The one war can be reloaded using Tomcat's manager application (see [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Reload_An_Existing_Application)).